# Calculate Slab Rates

Tags: c#

I want to calculate electricity cost according to slabs using C#, As in the below table

```
 SlabFrom    SlabTo      Rate

   0           100         5.00
  101          500         10.00
  501          Null        15.00
```

Number of slabs can change, Need a best solution to calculate total cost 
according to total usage. If total usage is 1,000 it should calculate:

(100 X 5) +  (400 X 10) + (500 X 15) = 12,000

```
public class Cost
{
    public decimal  SlabFrom { get; set; }  

    public decimal SlabTo { get; set; }  

    public bool SlabHour { get; set; }

    public decimal RatePerUnit { get; set; }
}

        var rates = new List<Cost>
        {
            new Cost()
            {
                SlabFrom = 0,
                SlabTo = 100,
                RatePerUnit = 5
            },
            new Cost()
            {
                SlabFrom = 101,
                SlabTo = 500,
                RatePerUnit = 10
            },
            new Cost()
            {
                SlabFrom = 501,
                SlabTo = 1000,
                RatePerUnit = 15
            },
            new Cost()
            {
                SlabFrom = 1001,
                SlabTo = 1500,
                RatePerUnit = 20
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please show some code and look at [mcve]

Comment: FWIW your `Cost` class can't store a null `SlabTo` as it stands.

Comment: You're getting some good answers now, but I'm worried that you haven't even attempted to create that sum yourself in your example code. Is this homework? We shouldn't be doing your homework for you.

Comment: The null represents infinite

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the first 3

```
int usage = 503;
int total = usage < 100 ? usage * 5 : 500 + (usage < 500 ? (usage - 100) * 10 : 4000 + (usage - 500) * 15);
 //4545
```

If you want a more generic answer
By the way i used your Cost class to test this

```
decimal used = 1000;
decimal LastSlabto = 0;
decimal total = 0;

foreach (Cost rate in rates)
{
   if (used > rate.SlabTo - LastSlabto)
      total += (rate.SlabTo - LastSlabto) * rate.RatePerUnit;
   else
   {
      total += used * rate.RatePerUnit;
      used = 0;
      break;
   }
   used -= rate.SlabTo - LastSlabto;
   LastSlabto = rate.SlabTo;             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
rates.TakeWhile(item => item.SlabFrom totalUsage)
     .Sum(item => (double)((item.SlabTo > totalUsage ? totalUsage : item.SlabTo) - item.SlabFrom) * item.RatePerUnit);
```

Comment: This should calculate for total usage, Total usage is input, Slab's are used to calculate the cost, It should use the range provided and calculate the cost.

Comment: @user6634447 - This gives the answer

Comment: @Rup - ya.. not sure what is meant with that `totalUsage`... - edited to try and take what I think he wants into account

Comment: @Rup - True.. didn't think about it at first. Now will take into account

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SlabFrom", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SlabTo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns["SlabTo"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(double));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,100,5.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {100,500,10.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {501,null,15.00});

            int usage = 1500;

            double cost = 0;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                if(usage > 0)
                {
                    if((row.Field<int?>("SlabTo") == null) || (usage < row.Field<int>("SlabTo")))
                    {
                        cost += usage * row.Field<double>("Rate");
                        usage = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         cost += (row.Field<int>("SlabTo") - row.Field<int>("SlabFrom")) * row.Field<double>("Rate");
                         usage -=  (row.Field<int>("SlabTo") - row.Field<int>("SlabFrom"));
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems a bit overkill! I don't think the `usage < SlabTo` test is still valid though if you're subtracting from usage.

Comment: Code was tested and got correct results.  Answer should be 19,500, not 12.000.  Second row of table should start at 100 (not 101) to get correct results.

Comment: I think your code will break if you add a fourth pricing row. Can you explain 19,500? I think the sum in the question looks correct. 100 vs 101 is probably discrete slabs counting inclusively then.

Comment: Only the last row should contain a NULL so it should work with any number of rows.   cost = (100 * 5) + (400 * 10) + (1000 * 15).  I based usage on 1500 (I think the number has been changed since original posting).

Comment: Ah OK, there was [an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13114153) that changed the input value in the question to 1000 not 1500, since both sides of the worked example were wrong => 12,000. But I agree 1500 => 19500. I thought an extra row was the best way to illustrate my concern but turns out there's an easier way: try input 501. Your code charges the last one at the 100-500 rate, not the 501+ rate.

Comment: You need top change the 101 to 100 to get 400 values.  My code is correct.  If you leave the number at 101 then there is issues with row 1 being off.  Row one and Row two must be consistent.

Comment: That's not the problem. If you try your code with usage=501 it gives 4510 whereas I think the answer is 4515. This is because after the first loop you've subtracted 100 from usage to get 401 and then you compare that against SlabTo=500 to see if the remainder lies within the second slab. Which it shouldn't, since usage was 501 originally, but your code thinks it does. But hey, I'll agree to disagree.

Comment: Normal progressive rate tables are calculated the way I did it.  Even the example posted was done this way.

Answer (score 0):

101-500 range is calculated as (500-101) * 10. However, it can be modified to match your requirement by doing minor changes.

```
private static double CalculateRate(int totalUsage)
{
    var applicableSlabRates = sr.Where(r => r.SlabFrom <= totalUsage).OrderBy(r => r.SlabFrom);

        double cost = 0;
        foreach (var r in applicableSlabRates)
        {
            int range = 0;
            if ((r.SlabFrom < totalUsage && totalUsage <= r.SlabTo) || r.SlabTo == null)
            {
                range = totalUsage;
            }
            else
            {
                range = Convert.ToInt32( r.SlabTo ) - r.SlabFrom;
            }

            cost += range * r.Rate;

            totalUsage = totalUsage - range;
        }

        return cost;
}


 public class SlabRate
 {
        public int SlabFrom { get; set; }
        public int? SlabTo { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
 }

 static List<SlabRate> sr = new List<SlabRate>();
    sr.Add(new SlabRate() { SlabFrom = 0, SlabTo = 100, Rate = 5.00 });
    sr.Add(new SlabRate() { SlabFrom = 101, SlabTo = 500, Rate = 10.00 });
    sr.Add(new SlabRate() { SlabFrom = 501, SlabTo = null, Rate = 15.00 });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above answer I got it right, Thanks. Please see

```
 private static double GenericCostCalculation(double units)
    {
        var rates = new List<Cost>
        {
            new Cost { SlabFrom = 0, SlabTo = 100, RatePerUnit = 10 },

            new Cost { SlabFrom = 101, SlabTo = 500, RatePerUnit = 20 },

            new Cost { SlabFrom = 501, SlabTo = 1000,RatePerUnit = 30 },

            new Cost { SlabFrom = 1001, SlabTo = 2000, RatePerUnit = 40 }
        };

        double cost = 0;
        foreach (var rate in rates)
        {
            if (units > 0)
            {
                if ((rate.SlabTo == rates.Max(x => x.SlabTo)) || (units < rate.SlabTo))
                {
                    cost += units * rate.RatePerUnit;
                    units = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cost += (rate.SlabTo - rate.SlabFrom) * rate.RatePerUnit;
                    units -= (rate.SlabTo - rate.SlabFrom);
                }
            }
        }
        return cost;
    }
```

Comment: No, that's not right for the same reason I commented on jdweng's answer below: subtracting from units to get a 'number left' then comparing against 'SlabTo', which is fixed, is wrong and you'll get the wrong answer for 501 for example. Also for charging the full range you're using `(rate.SlabTo - rate.SlabFrom)`, which is off-by-one, since the SlabFrom value appears to be inclusive - and that one propagates into the most-expensive range charged. There's probably better ways to do the off-the-top-of-the-range check too rather than finding Max(SlabTo) in every rate iteration.